Bekenstein experiment to reveal the quantum foam
Bekenstein proposed an experiment to experimentally verify the Planck-scale space-time quantization. However, this has not been verified by subsequent actual experiments. What is it that cannot be achieved as of now?
Experiment to reveal the quantum foam

Are you asking what makes this experiment too difficult to do i.e. why no-one has done it yet?

Yes, that's right. Are there any problems with measurements or other conditions?

This paper

Maclay, G. J., Wadood, S. A., Black, E. D., & Milonni, P. W. (2019). Effect of quantum and thermal jitter on the feasibility of Bekenstein’s proposed experiment to search for Planck-scale signals. Physical Review D, 99(12), 124053, DOI:10.1103/PhysRevD.99.124053.

reevaluated the feasibility of that experiment with this conclusion:

An analysis of the quantum and thermal jitter of the block shows that it greatly diminishes the possibility that the experiment could reveal Planck-scale signals.

